# What is the best way to display results of a user satisfaction survey?

Tags: icons, surveys, dashboard

I have a user satisfaction survey with 3 'emojis' as options. They display 'sad', 'neutral' and 'happy'. I'm looking for a way to display the results of those in a dashboard. Are there any things I should look out for, or are the 3 emojis enough to display the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sad to say that it depends on your goals. For example,

- mood barometer, if you'd like to show overall mood trend
- mood survey, if you're interested in showing detail information about each mood
- mood stacked – same as a mood survey, but more informative.

[image: a user satisfaction survey results]

I could find 10+ options for this, so what's the best way to display results of a user satistifactions survey depends on your goals and should be tested with your users.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the results in a simple bar chart with counts for number of sad, neutral and happy, however this will not be very interesting for your dashboard unless you can make it update in real time.

If you were capturing users sentiment live, you can produce a trend line to show how that sentiment is changing over time, e.g.

- If someone selects "sad", then reduce trend line height by 1
- If someone selects "happy", then increase trend line height by 1
- If someone selects "neutral", then trend line continues at the same level

In this way if lots of people are selecting "happy" the trend line will shoot up, and if lots of people are selecting "sad" the trend line will shoot down. You could also change the colour of the trend line when it hits certain thresholds.

Answer (score 0):

**Capturing user sentiments is best represented visually and with a percentage alloted to each reaction**(more intuitive),the same is shown below as a reference : 
[image]

On hovering you can use your CSS skills to make the selection stand out using the colors scheme as per the shown selection.